# Why does this navigation item disappear in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nvntm/1/

The "Support" navigation item actually disappears on Firefox (and other similar browsers), leaving only the other three navigation items.  Why is this so? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Did you try expanding the width of the result box that your HTML is displaying in?

Comment: In which browsers does it display?

Comment: @BoltClock: It had problems on Linux-based machines, as well as in Firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not enough width in the containing `<ul>` for all the child `<li>` items. Are you able to increase the fixed width to 670px?

The reason for that is probably due to different browser's different default CSS for elements. Do you have a good "reset" CSS in your app?

Comment: Thanks!  I was suspecting that might be the case.  Yes, I'm using Eric's reset.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the nav css to show the overflow demonstrates that the nav items are simply being wrapped to the next line.

Fix this by increasing the width past 660px (exact working value for your example is 668px):

```
.nav_centered ul {

overflow: visible;
width: 668px;
```

Keep overflow on while you are adjusting the width to see the wrapped contents, otherwise you can turn it back off. It is purely to help with visualization. Hope this helps :)

Comment: `overflow: show` isn't a CSS property... don't you mean `overflow: visible`?